# Avoid drawRect Method for iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

Currently making a universal application in which, I m using drawRect method for displaying an image on navigationBar for iPhone app, but I don't want to use this method for iPad.

I have created a category for changing UINavigationBar. In which I did the following.

```
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)   
    { 
        // iPad mode ... dont load anything 
    }
    else 
    {
        // iphone mode .... use an image 
    }
```

After this its displaying a black empty space instead of navigation bar for iPad. For iPhone it works fine.

I tried using self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault; in my both Matser & Detail views in viewDidLoad , but still it displays black empty space.

How can I avoid drawRect method call when device is iPad.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you were subclassing `UINavigationBar`, you should just use the right navigation bar class on each platform. In other words, the interface idiom check should affect *creation* of the navigation bar, rather than its `drawRect:` implementation.

Since you are using a category to replace the `drawRect:` implementation (which you shouldn't do), I think your only choice is dynamic method swizzling. That is, you replace `drawRect:` only on iPhone/iPod Touch.

Consider subclassing `UINavigationBar` as it is easier, safer and cleaner. That will help you avoid compatibility headaches.

EDIT: to provide an example, assume that you have a nib file containing only an empty navigation controller with a custom `UINavigationBar` subclass. To do that select the navigation bar in the xib editor and change its class in the inspector.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = nil;

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
else {
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName: @"MyNavigationController" bundle: nil];
    navigationController = [[[nib instantiateWithOwner: nil options: nil] objectAtIndex: 0] retain];
}
```

When run on an iPhone or an iPod Touch, this code will create a navigation controller from the nib file.

Comment: How can I call drawRect only for iPhone/iPod touch.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `[super drawRect]` at the beginning of the method, it will call the default implementation which will draw the `UINavigationBar` normally.

The reason that you should not do a custom subclass is that `UINavigationController` instantiates it's `UINavigationBar` directly and you cannot tell it to use your subclass.

Comment: I tried calling [super drawRect] for iPad, but its still displaying a black bar.